# Angular2 Reactive Forms and BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-observable

I am new to Angular and cannot figure out updating reactive forms with async calls.

I have a reactive form based on an object model. Any change in the form triggers an HTTP request that might send back an updated version of the object as a response. I need to update the form accordingly.

I implemented a similar thing (list of those objects) with BehaviorSubject, but not sure how to do it with a form.

EDIT: Sorry for not including code. It is rather messy, so here is a summary.

Here is what I have right now:

```
export class EditQuestionnaire implements OnInit {

    questionnaireForm: FormGroup;

    questionnaire: Observable<Questionnaire>;

    // constructor with its dependencies omitted

    ngOnInit() {
        this.questionnaireForm = this.fb.group({
            'id': [''],
            'submitted': [false],
            'questions': this.fb.array(
                   []
            ),
        });
        this.questionnaire = this.questionnaireService.getQuestionnaireGeneral(); // This is an observable of a BehaviorSubject that gets updated in a service with every call to getQuestionnaire

        this.questionnaireService
            .getQuestionnaire(this.questionnaire.id)
            .subscribe(questionnaire => {
                this.questionnaireForm = this.loadQuestionnaire(questionnaire); // loads the questionnaire into the form
            });
    }
    ...
}
```

What I also have is a child component denoting a question in the questionnaire. Here I detect the changes:

```
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() questionForm: FormGroup;
    @Input() questionnaireId: string;

    // constructor and dependencies omitted

    get text() {
        return this.questionForm.get('text') as FormControl;
    }
    get answers() {
        return this.questionForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    }
    get id() {
        return this.questionForm.get('id') as FormControl;
    }
    get comment() {
        return this.questionForm.get('comment') as FormControl;
    }   

    ngOnInit() {
        const questionId = this.id.value;
        this.comment.valueChanges
                    .pipe(
                         debounce(() => interval(2000))
                     )
                    .subscribe(newValue => {
                         this.saveComment(questionId, newValue);
                     });

        for (const answer of this.answers.controls) {
            this.answers.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                const answerId = answer.get('id').value;
                this.saveAnswer(questionId, answer);
        });
    }

    saveComment(questionId: string, comment: string) {
        this.questionnaireService.updateComment(questionnaireId, questionId, comment).subscribe(); // no need to rebuild here
    }

    saveAnswer(questionId: string, answerId: string) {
        this.questionnaireService.updateAnswer(questionnaireId, questionId, answerId).subscribe(questionnaire => { /* trigger the form to rebuild */ })
    }
}
```

Answers to certain questions might trigger follow-up questions, so a whole new questionnaire is sent back from the back end. The problem I am encountering here is that the valueChanges listeners identify the new questionnaire as a change, and my application gets stuck in an infinite loop of HTTP requests.

Any ideas how to work around this problem?

UPDATE:

I eventually ended up using an EventEmitter to pass the received questionnaire object to the parent component, where I rebuild the form.

Comment: You should use stackblitz or plunker to show, what you tried to do. So others can help you

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh I apologize, here is the code

Comment: @TheHeadRush sorry, updated with the code

Comment: Downvote retracted. Manual change detection is what you need. Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges` when you want the changes detected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you trigger the request from a service through the component. To update a reactive form object from your component, you can assign it directly. For instance, if you declare your reactive form like this:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl()
})
```

You can update the name simply like this:

```
let name = "Kyle";
this.form.controls.name.value = name;
```

Found in the Angular documentation here:

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: sorry, the question was originally vague, I included the code.

Comment: @aygestan ooh yea, no longer a noob question. Wise people who decide not to answer a vague question avoid downvotes for un-relevant answers